# Can't link to a previously defined variable in _settings.scss

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I have setup foundation using SASS and love it. However, there is one thing I'm having trouble with which makes absolutely no sense to me.

I have my main scss file (global.scss) setup like so:

```
@import "settings";  
@import "normalize";  
@import "foundation";
```

This all works fine. However, when I try and use my own variables file, called _variables.scss and use a variable declared in this file in _settings.scss I get a sass compile error:

```
Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$strongcolor".  
        on line 53 of scss/_settings.scss  
        from line 3 of scss/global.scss
```

But I don't see how it can be undeclared, since I have imported my _variables.scss file ABOVE @import "settings";

When I manually declare the variable like this:

```
$strongcolour:  #396620;  
@import "settings";
```

Everything compiles, but trying to do:

```
@import "variables"; (which has the exact same variable defined inside of it)  
@import "settings";
```

It gives the error message. I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

It works now for some reason, I think there were other variables depending on other files somewhere. Either way, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found it was a problem with my Gulpfile.js.
The program tried to process every file independently.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.